# Curl able to do this if not can anyone point me in the right direction?

Tags: php, curl

Let's say my customer inputs their vehicle number and id on my website. Is there any way to automate it that the system can go to `https://vrl.lta.gov.sg/lta/vrl/action/pubfunc?ID=EnquireRebateBeforeDeReg` and when the customer enters the values, retrieve all the car details from the site and store it on my server?

My website is coded in php. Can someone please point me at the right direction or provide me some examples of such code?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not possible. You can either request the user input all the information on your site or input all the information on the destination site. Unless you have access to modify the destination site, there is no way to retrieve the information remotely.

You may wish to see if the destination site provides some API or web services that you can access that will allow you to retrieve the data based on vehicle number and ID.